# PlayOnLinux: change install location from virtual drive

Tags: hard-drive, playonlinux

I am using PLayOnLinux for a couple of my games but it only installs games in one specific spot that I am unable to change, I'm guessing it's a virtual drive ((according to someone on here)) and I'd like to know how to change it to one of my actual harddrives, seeing as said virtual drive runs out of space.

Answer (score 6):

PlayOnLinux creates a "virtual drive" for every program you install through it. By default they're in your home folder in a folder called `.PlayOnLinux`

You can move the location of all the current virtual drives and any more drives you're going to install.

let's say you want to put them here: `/mnt/NewPlayOnLinuxFolder/`

so firstly copy the folder `.PlayOnLinux` to the new directory:

```
cp -av ~/.PlayOnLinux /mnt/NewPlayOnLinuxFolder/
```

after that's done, remove the old folder:

```
rm -rf ~/.PlayOnLinux
```

then make what's called a "symbolic link" (as I understand, this would make anything "referring to" the old directory go to the new directory instead.)

```
ln -s /mnt/NewPlayOnLinuxFolder/.PlayOnLinux ~/.PlayOnLinux
```

That's it

[source](http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/How_to_move_PlayOnLinux_virtual_drives_to_another_disk)

Comment: If you want to keep the POL configuration inside the home directory but move the Wine prefixes you can append the sub-directory `wineprefixes` to all the paths mentioned in the answer.